# Process command using python

Tags: python, process, command

I want to pick up the command and its arguments in Python.

I can use

```
process=os.popen('ps -elf').read().split("\n")
```

and then use regular expression to extract the command but its ugly.

psutils returns a process name but not the actual commands and arguments

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can use `psutil.Process(pid).cmdline()` to get the command line and its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`psutil` can get the command line arguments:

```
import psutil

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    cmd_line = p.cmdline()
    if cmd_line:
        print(cmd_line)
```

EDIT: updated to fix the issue found by @Keir

Comment: This would be helpful if it worked   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

The last suggestion is almost correct.
It should be

```
for p in psutil.process_iter():
   cline = p.cmdline
   if cline: print(cline)
```